# Crypt setup successful, stuck after correct password input

Tags: boot, encryption

Ubuntu 18.04 there.

The whole thing happened after restarting the system after installing Chinese language pack. After encryption password input it shows crypt setup successful, but after that it blinks with black screen (It used to do that before the issue while switching to display wallpaper/desktop view), and unfortunately it's stuck there after displaying ubuntu progress bar again and a mouse cursor. I believe it must be something related to the UI layer, but not sure how to debug and fix that so any input and hints will be greatly appreciated. I can access recovery mode and verified all the files are there, there is no issue with memory in any of listed partitions. Nvidia drivers issue doesn't apply to me. On top of that I'm pretty sure the OS is still trying to process sth, because the cpu fan is running (not super heavy (it does at 65C+, but still - normally it sits quiet until reaching 40C I believe).

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: It would be sufficient to just tell me what steps would you take to understand the issue first, I can google around how to do them - that's not the problem, just can't proceed after reading several issues with a similar description.

Comment: The "UI layer" is Plymouth before account login/password (not encryption passphrase) and X or Wayland after login. Not sure which you refer to. Since you can access Recovery Mode, check `/var/log/syslog` for errors around the appropriate time(s).

Comment: probably I don't know what to look for there, I've noticed that apt-get update wasn't working but after removing resolv.conf link and restarting NetworkManager I was able to run package repair, but it didn't solve the issue. Nothing really suspicious in the logs, unless I should look for sth different then failures. :(

Comment: ctrl+alt+f1 somehow fixed the problem. Found that random shortcut somewhere. Wow.

Comment: now imagine what could I have broke while trying to fix that :))